# Adding items based of status of checkboxes for a list of products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am displaying a list of products on a page, and beside each product I have a checkbox.

Now when the user submits the form, I need to grab the product id's and then add those products to a shopping cart.

Each checkbox would be like:

```
<input type=checkbox value=39827 ... />
```

Is there a cool rails way of getting all the id's, or do I have to do this in my action method that handles the post:

```
def add_products_to_cart

  @products = Product.find_....

  @products.each do |p|
     // check if checkbox form key exists, if it is selected, add to cart

  end

end
```

Note: The above pattern is what I have been doing with other frameworks, I'm curious if there is a **Rails Way** to do this.

Comment: what is the "name" value of the checkbox input? `product_ids[]` I guess?

Comment: @MrYoshiji whatever you want it to be, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# view
# somethings like this (HAML):
- products.each do |product|
  = check_box_tag 'product_ids[]', product.id, false
  # Usage: check_box_tag(name, value = '1', checked = false, options = {})

# which generate this kind of HTML:
<input type="checkbox" value="39827" name="product_ids[]" />
```

And then in the Controller:

```
# controller's action receiving the params after submitting the form
def add_products_to_cart
  # here params[:product_ids] should contain an array of ids, the checked ones
  @products = Product.where(id: params[:product_ids])

  @products.each do |product|
    # your logic to add a product in your cart, something like
    if current_user.can_access?(product) # logic to prevent User from adding forbidden products
      my_cart << product
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Don't hesitate to ask any question if needed!

Comment: one thing though, a person could hack the html and pass in product id's that they might not have permission to.

Comment: That's why you have to add a server-side verification on what products the user can access to. I update my answer in consequence